# Xoops - Why I get an array and not a XoopsObject?

Tags: php, content-management-system, portal

I try to get an object from my handler but when I try to know if it is an object with 'is_object', the answer is false and the answer to 'is_array' is true.

Why ?

This is my code :

```
        // Get members list
        $criteria = new CriteriaCompo();
        $criteria->setSort('member_id');
        $criteria->setOrder('ASC');
        $members = $memberhandler->getObjects($criteria, true, false);
        unset($criteria);

        // Get  Nickname / Pseudo
        if (count($members) > 0) {
            foreach (array_keys($members) as $i) {
                is_object($members[$i]) ? print_r("is object") : print_r("is not object");
                is_object($members[0]) ? print_r("is object") : print_r("is not object");
                is_array($members[$i]) ? print_r("is array") : print_r("is not array");
                echo($member->getVar('uid'));
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: try `var_dump($members)` before loop, and show what results are.

Answer (score 1):

It is because "getObjects" is getting you an "array of objects"

If you want to retrieve a particular object, and have the member_id, then you should use "get", and in your case you wouldn't use the "criteria" anymore, but request the object directly:

$member = $memberhandler->get($member_id);

You can see more examples in this presentation:

http://www.slideshare.net/xoopsproject/oop-adventures-with-xoops